# Is there something wrong with this Rails Console error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

Very new to Rails, so bear with me -

Currently paranoid that my ruby and gem versions aren't up to date because I'd occasionally get error messages when running `rails test`. Previously had rvm and rbenv both installed, but wow I've removed both and reinstalled rvm only.

When I go into a `irb` and call an action that doesn't work, such as: `"foo".select`, I get a simple error message:

```
NoMethodError: private method 'select' called for "foo":String
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/irb:11:in '<main>'
```

However, when I type the same command `"foo".select` in `rails console` instead, I get:

```
NoMethodError: private method `select' called for "foo":String
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/Joseph/workspace/sample_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Is this normal? Or is there something wrong with my gems here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your gems. The thing is that when you run irb, it's just that. You only run the ruby interactive.
When you run `rails console` in order to show you the console it needs to go and set it for you with ActiveRecord, rails core, etc. So this (below) is all it does before it's set.

```
from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/Joseph/workspace/sample_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sample_app/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/Joseph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Notice that irb is executed really fast, while rails console takes its time,  depending on your initializers, configurations, etc.

Comment: @JosephLiu I can see that you never accept answers provided to your questions. When you ask a question, other users put effort to help you solve your problem. You should pick the best answer (if it indeed helped you) and accept it (look for checkmark near the answer's score). This way you let the community know, that your problem is solved and also you reward the user, who helped you.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with you @AndreyDeineko :)

Comment: @JGutierrezC one more thing - you can only accept one answer per question :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko huh? Maybe is because it's way late here in my country, but i didn't understand that. I think it's impossible to accept more than one answer as the right one.

Comment: @JGutierrezC absolutely. I specified this exclusively because I have seen newcomers, who were clicking checkmark on all answers in their thread, but logically of course - selecting one answer means selecting one answer.

Comment: Had no idea how to do so. Thanks